# Routing Areas MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a small system with four areas, when I test it in Localhost, it works fine, but when I publish it in IIS 7.5 it does not find the routes of any area

I have tried adding namespaces in the route config, in the config of the areas and it does not work in any way

File RouteConfig:

```
namespace Gamma
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            //routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Areas:

File AdministradorAreaRegistration

```
namespace Gamma.Areas.Administrador
{
    public class AdministradorAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Administrador";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Administrador_default",
                "Administrador/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

File GestorAreaRegistration

```
namespace Gamma.Areas.Gestor
{
    public class GestorAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Gestor";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                 "Gestor_default",
                 "Gestor/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
        }
    }
}
```

File UsuarioAreaRegistration

```
namespace Gamma.Areas.Usuario
{
    public class UsuarioAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Usuario";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Usuario_default",
                "Usuario/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers:

Start of the application

Home

Areas:

HomeAdminController
VehiculoController
ProveedorController

HomeGestorController
VehiculoController
ProveedorController

HomeUsuarioController
VehiculoController
ProveedorController

Global.asax

```
namespace Gamma
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

In Account Controllers Login

```
 switch (ViewBag.RoleName)
                                {
                                    case "Admin":

                                        return RedirectToAction("Bienvenida", "HomeAdmin", new { @area = "Administrador" });

                                    case "Usuario":
                                        return RedirectToAction("Bienvenida", "HomeUsuario", new { @area = "Usuario" });

                                    case "Gestor":
                                        return RedirectToAction("Bienvenida", "HomeGestor", new { @area = "Gestor" });

                                    case "Cliente":
                                        return RedirectToAction("Bienvenida", "HomeClientes", new { @area = "Clientes" });

                                    default:
                                        return RedirectToAction("Bienvenida", "HomeUsuario", new { @area = "Usuario" });
```

In Localhost works fine

In IIS:

Error.
Error al procesar la solicitud.
Administrador/HomeAdmin/Bienvenida

In the tests he tells me he can not find the route

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
________________________________________
No se encuentra el recurso.
Descripción: HTTP 404. El recurso que está buscando (o una de sus dependencias) se puede haber quitado, haber cambiado de nombre o no estar disponible temporalmente. Revise la dirección URL siguiente y asegúrese de que está escrita correctamente. 

Dirección URL solicitada: /Administrador/HomeAdmin/Bienvenida
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the Global.asax file with `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```